# Multiple Threads or Workers in Python? - Want to increase Performance

Tags: python, multithreading, worker

Currently, I got some little Python Script running, creating some Web-Requests.
I am absolute new to Python, so I took a bare-bones Script I found, and it uses Multi-Threads (see end of thread for the full Script):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
threads = []
for i in range(THREAD_COUNT):
    t = Thread(target=callback)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

However, I feel this Script is kinda slow, like it does the Requests after each other and not at the same time.

So I took another approach and tried to find more about Workers and Multi-Threads.
It seems "Workers" are the Way to go, instead of Threads?

So I took the following from a Tutorial and modified it a little:

```
import logging
import os
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from time import time

from multi import callback


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class DownloadWorker(Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # that is my Function in Multi.py (A simple Web Request Function)      
            try:
                callback()
            finally:
                self.queue.task_done()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ts = time()
    queue = Queue()
    for x in range(8):
        worker = DownloadWorker(queue)        
        worker.daemon = True
        worker.start()
    # I put that here, because I want to run my "Program" infinite times
    for i in range(500000):
        logger.info('Queueing')
        queue.put(i)
    
    queue.join()
    logging.info('Took %s', time() - ts)
```

I am not sure here, if that is the correct approach, from my Understanding I created 8 Workers and with the queue.put(i). I give them Jobs (500,000 in this Case?) passing them the current counter (which does nothing, it seems to be required tho?)

After he is done queening, the Function is executed, as I can see in my Console.
However, I feel it still runs same slow as before?

(My Original Request File)

```
from threading import Thread
import requests
import json
import string
import urllib3
import threading

THREAD_COUNT = 5

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


def callback():
    counter = 0
    try:
        while True:            
            print("Prozess " + str(threading.get_ident())+ " " +str(counter))
            counter = counter + 1 
            response = requests.post('ourAPIHere',verify=False, json={"pingme":"hello"})
            json_data = json.loads(response.text)
            if json_data["status"] == "error":
                print("Server Error? Check logs!")
            if json_data["status"] == "success":
                print("OK")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    for i in range(THREAD_COUNT):
        t = Thread(target=callback)
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Comment: If this is slow (or too slow for your needs) I suggest putting some timing information before POST and after json.loads because my suspicion is that it's the API that's not performing as you would hope. As an aside, the way you plan to stop this program from running is a bit *avant-garde*

Comment: You culd look in to multiprocessing aswell

Comment: @JCaesar yep indeed, when I add timing, some requests take up to 15 or 20 sec to return, in that case I feel the "Program" is slowing down. Does that mean the "Threads" wait on each other?

Comment: They do not wait on/for each other. They run concurrently